# MPICH3 not running on multiple mahines: hydra_pmi_poxy error : Exec format error

Tags: mpi, ubuntu-14.04, mpich

I set up MPICH3 (mpich-3.1.3) on my notebook(Intel Core i5) and a slave processor running on ARM Cortex15 processor and both running Ubuntu 14.04 OS with ssh keygen setup for free communication.

I have installed mpich3 in the folder which is shared between the cluster through nfs.

I have exported the path from my master server only.
The installation went well and i tried out the following command on my master node alone which runs fine:

```
    mpiexec -n 2 ./cpi
    Process 0 of 2 is on MingF
    Process 1 of 2 is on MingF
    pi is approximately 3.1415926544231341, Error is 0.0000000008333410
    wall clock time = 0.000182
```

But when I try running on my slave and master, then i get this error and it hangs:

```
    mpiexec -f hosts -n 2 ./cpi
    bash: /mirror/mpich3/bin/hydra_pmi_proxy: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

It hangs there until i press 'Ctrl + C' to break out of it.

I am guessing its because of the change in processor type but I may be wrong. could someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot run the same executable on such different architectures as x86 and ARM. Compile it separately on both machines and pay attention to the endianness of the ARM machine.

Comment: I used nfs for installing and installed it on my master system(/mirror folder) and mounted it on my slave's /mirror folder. If i install it on my slave separately and compile it, and make sure that the folders match then would i still need to mount the folder again?

Comment: It us up to you, but you cannot use the same executable.